# Can I get Tibbles to Display like Data Tables

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, tibble

One of the things I love about data tables is that when you show them from the command line they give you the head and tail of them....

I am now being made to work in dplyr a lot and find it very frustrating that tibbles don't do this....

Is there a way of setting up R / RStudio to get tibbles to show you the head and tail?

Comment: you can do: `library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  as.data.frame()


iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  print(n=150)`

Comment: Check [here](https://pillar.r-lib.org/articles/extending.html#body) for how tibbles are displayed under the hood. I'd be happy to see a solution using this, as I'm not really knowledgable with this framework

Comment: I think that is the sort of approach I was hoping for, where a environment setting could be changed or something, like tbl_format_setup() it seems

Answer (score 1):

If this is something you want to do often, you could write a little function to do it.  Below `headtail()` takes the data frame and `n` as the input and prints the head and tail of the data.

```r
headtail <- function(x, n=10, ungroup = TRUE, ...){
  if(ungroup)x <- dplyr::ungroup(x)
  hd <- dplyr::slice_head(x, n=n)
  tl <- dplyr::slice_tail(x, n=n)
  print(hd)
  cat("...\n")
  print(tl)
}
mtcars <- dplyr::as_tibble(mtcars)
headtail(mtcars, n=2)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 11
#>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#> 2    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#> ...
#> # A tibble: 2 × 11
#>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  15       8   301   335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     5     8
#> 2  21.4     4   121   109  4.11  2.78  18.6     1     1     4     2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You might want to ungroup `x` first incase it's a grouped data frame and may return more rows than expected.

Comment: Thanks @NicChr, I updated the function to have an `ungroup` option argument that defaults to true.  If someone wants the head and tail by group, they should be able to do it, but the default is to ungroup the data first.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky way would be to change the default print method for tbl. I do not recommend it because of undesired side effects

```r
library(dplyr)
print.tbl <- data.table:::print.data.table

iris_tbl <- as_tibble(iris)
iris_tbl
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#>  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
#>  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
#>  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
#>  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
#>  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
#> ---                                                            
#> 146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
#> 147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
#> 148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
#> 149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
#> 150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica

iris_tbl %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())
#>      Species  n
#> 1:     setosa 50
#> 2: versicolor 50
#> 3:  virginica 50
```

Comment: Any documentation on those potential side effects?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those suggestions - all rather complicated it seems - I think I was hoping just for some sort of easy environment setting I could change.

Can anyone think of a problem with just using setDT() to make it behave like a data table, whilst, I presume, it leaves the tibble intact as it is only setting it as a data able by reference?

This also allows me to use all data table functionality too - so it seems a bit of a win:win?  Unless I am missing something?

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
#Create the tibble
iris_tbl <- as_tibble(iris)


setDT(iris_tbl)
iris_tbl
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
 ---                                                            
146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
```